# How to increase the size of memory region allocated with mmap()

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls, mmap, arm64

I'm allocating memory using `mmap` Linux syscall.

```
        mov     x5, 0                   ; offset is zero
        mov     x4, -1                  ; no file descriptor
        mov     x3, 0x22                ; MAP_PRIVATE + MAP_ANONYMOUS
        mov     x2, 3                   ; PROT_READ + PROT_WRITE
        mov     x1, 4096                ; initial region size in bytes 
        mov     x0, 0                   ; let Linux choose region address
        mov     x8, 222                 ; mmap
        svc     0
```

Is it possible to increase the size of allocated memory region preserving its start address and contents? How to do it properly?

Comment: The question is about linux and independent of assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, use the [`mremap(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) Linux-specific system call *without* `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` to extend the existing mapping, without considering the option of remapping those physical pages to a different virtual address where there's enough room for the larger mapping.

It will return an error if some other mapping already exists for the pages you want to grow into.  (Unlike `mmap(MAP_FIXED)` which will silently replace those mappings.)

If you're writing in asm, portability to non-Linux is barely relevant; other OSes will have different call numbers and maybe ABIs, so just look up `__NR_mremap` in `asm/unistd.h`, and get the `flags` patterns from `sys/mman.h`.

---

With just portable POSIX calls, `mmap()` with a non-NULL hint address = right after you existing mapping, but without `MAP_FIXED`; it will pick that address if the pages are free (and as @datenwolf says, merge with the earlier mapping into one long extent).  Otherwise it will pick somewhere else.  (Then you have to `munmap` that mapping that ended up not where you wanted it.)

There is a Linux-specific `mmap` option: `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` will return an error instead of mapping at an address different from the hint.  Kernels older than 4.17 don't know about that flag and will typically treat it as if you used no other flags besides `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, so you should check the return value against the hint.

Do not use `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE | MAP_FIXED`; that would act as `MAP_FIXED` on old kernels, and maybe also on new kernels that do know about `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`.

Assuming you know the start of the mapping you want to extend, and the desired new total size, `mremap` is a better choice than `mmap(MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE)`.  It's been supported since at least Linux 2.4, i.e. decades, and keeps the existing mapping flags and permissions automatically (e.g. MAP_PRIVATE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE)

If you only knew the end address of the existing mapping, `mmap(MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE)` might be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If there's free virtual address space behind your original region, just create an additional mmap-ed region right behind the original one, using the `MAP_FIXED | MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` flags and identical permissions. If the page size of both regions are identical, they'll be coalesced into single mapping.

Comment: "If there's free virtual address space behind your original region".  The problem is how to reliably determine whether that is the case.

Comment: The easiest method is to just *try* it with the noreplace flag set (*edited my answer accordingly*). `mmap` is either all or nothing (the function call doesn't have a channel that'd allow to pass back the size of the mapped region to the caller). If you want to forgo portability and limit yourself to Linux you can always parse `/proc/self/maps`

Comment: But `MAP_FIXED` doesn't "try"; it silently replaces the existing mapping if there was one.  `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` could help, but in that case Peter's `mremap` is equivalent and probably simpler.  And parsing `/proc/fixed/maps` is racy unless you are very careful; standard library functions could allocate more memory before you get a chance to create your new mapping.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I did edit my answer for exactly that remark. Race conditions are an issue only in multithreaded processes; in a single threaded process if all allocations are prepared before reading `/p/s/maps` and only syscalls are used, the VM map doesn't change.

Comment: @datenwolf: Pretty sure you should only use `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`, not `MAP_FIXED | MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`.  They're separate options, and you want the fallback for old kernels that don't know about `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` to be the normal behaviour of disregarding the hint if there's a conflict, not of MAP_FIXED.  Good point that `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` *is* another way to do this safely, though.  (I added that to my answer with what I think is a correct description of how to use it.)